# large families of small subsets with large symmetric differences

Tags: coding-theory

Define $\;\; f \: : \: \{0,1,2,3,...\} \: \to \: \{0,1,2,3,...\} \;\;$ by having $\:f(n)$ be

the number of elements in the largest subsets $\mathbf{S}$ of $\:2^{\{0,1,2,...,\hspace{.01 in}n-1\}}$ such that 

for all members $\:X,Y,Z\:$ of $\hspace{.02 in}\mathbf{S}$, $\;\;\;$ if $\;\; X$[$\Delta$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference)$ Y \: \subseteq \: Z \;\;$ then $ \; X=Y \;\;\;\; $ .

I can see that $\: \hspace{.01 in}f(0) = 1 = \hspace{.01 in}f(1) \:$ and $\: \hspace{.01 in}f(2) = 2 \:$ and $\: \hspace{.01 in}f(3) = 3 \:$ and

for all non-negative integers $m$ and $n$,

$f(m) \cdot f(n) \: \leq \: \hspace{.01 in}f(m+n) \;\;$ and $\;\; f(n) \leq \hspace{.02 in}\max\left(1,2^n-2\right) \;\;$.

It follows that, for all non-negative integers $n$, $\;\; 2^{\lfloor n/3\rfloor} \leq \hspace{.01 in}f(n) \:\:\:$.

> What more can be said about $\:f\hspace{.015 in}$? $\;\;$ I'm particularly interested in lower bounds on $\:f$.

(The application is in cryptography, although the statement doesn't involve crypto.)

Comment: It seems the following. Suppose that $1\le k<n$, and there is a set ${\bf S}\subset 2^{\{0,1,2,\dots,n-1\}}$ such that each element of $\bf S$ has exactly $k$-elements and $d_h(x,y)\ge k+1$ for every different elements $x,y\in S$, where $d_h$ is Hamming distance. Then the set $\bf S$ satisfies your conditions and yields a lower bound $f(n)\ge |S|$. You can 
estimate the size of a maximal such $\bf S$ from the below using a standard covering ball estimation.

Comment: Also you can search such the sets $\bf S$ among the examples of a sets ${\bf S}’\subset 2^{\{0,1,2,\dots,n-1\}}$ with $d_h(x,y)\ge k+1$ for every different elements $x,y\in {\bf S}’$, which should be well known in coding theory.

Comment: Would the first of your comments work by, so to speak, showing that one can move a significant number of points from an error-correcting code to give them $k$ 1s? $\:$ If no, then where would I look for "error-correcting $k$-element sets"? $\;\;$

Comment: I did not propose to modify existing error-correcting codes, but I expect that among them you can find codes with a large subset of elements with $k$ 1’s (even it is enough to have not greater than $k$ 1’s) .

Comment: Yes, such codes are investigated. See, for instance, the paper "[Unsolved Problems in Graph Theory Arising from the Study of Codes](http://webfile.ru/6565147)” by N. J. A. Sloane. Also you can try to find such codes at N.J.A. Sloane's web page.